# virt-install cpu0 unhandled rdmsr

Tags: centos, kvm, virtualization, qemu

I'm trying to install a guest VM using KVM on a partition.  I use `virt-install`.  I call the following command:

```
virt-install -n centos --ram=1536 --vcpus=1 --cdrom=/var/lib/libvirt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso --disk /dev/mapper/vg_vmhost-lv_centos
```

The VM boots up to install - the Welcome to CentOS 6.5! screen with the five options to install or upgrade, install with basic video drive, rescue, boot from local drive, or do a memory test shows up.  Then the following messages display:

```
Loading vmlinuz
Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok...............ready.
kvm: 2617: cpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0xc0010001
```

And then it hangs without installing CentOS.

I've searched for this error and the pages I've read haven't been helpful at all.  [This one](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=874627), for example, indicates that the messages are harmless.

My host machine is a headless CentOS 6.5 minimal install, and I'm trying to install the same on the intended VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are attempting to view the installation using `virsh console`, you need to configure the guest to output to the virtual serial console. From the boot screen you can press "Esc" which will bring up a prompt to provide additional boot options. Enter the following:

```
linux console=ttyS0,115200 utf8
```

This will start the text-mode installation over the virtual serial console. Another option is to use libvirt's VNC to perform the guest installation. To do this on a headless server, you can use X11 forwarding:

```
ssh -X yourhost
virt-manager
```

From the virt-manager GUI you can open a VNC connection (default) to the guest OS.

Sources:
[RHEL6 Administration Guide: Troubleshooting with serial consoles](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting_-Troubleshooting_with_serial_consoles.html)
[RHEL6 Installation Guide: Additional Boot Options](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-Boot-x86.html#s2-x86-starting-bootopts)